# Try Catch Bad Practice Flow Control Dilemma

Tags: exception, try-catch

I am aware that doing **Flow Control** on a program using a `try-catch` block is bad practice, but I can't see how to do it in another way when the error caught needs a redirection of the code's execution.

For example, let's say I have screen where the user clicks a button, and on the buttons click I execute some code. After the code ends execution, I redirect the user to a new screen....

... But the code execution can failure, and in that case, I need to let the user know of the failure and redirect him to the previous screen.

The way I will do it is (C# example, but I think this is more of a not language related question, more like good practices on coding in general) :

```
try
{
     ExcuteCode();  // Some code that can throw some Exception, it can be a .NET framework method or something else.
     NavigateToNextScreen();
} 
catch(Exception e) 
{
     Log.Write(e);
     ShowErrorMessage();
     GoBack();
}
```

Even if I change this to:

```
bool hasError = false;

try
{
     ExecuteCode();
} 
catch(Exception e) 
{
      Log.Write(e);
      ShowErrorMessage();
      hasError = true;
 } 

  if(hasError) { GoBack(); } 
  else { NavigateToNextScreen();}
```

It's still doing **Flow Control** inside the `try-catch` block.

So, is it there a recommend way to handle this properly and avoid this bad practice?

Comment: Not sure what language it is but if method/function `ExecuteCode` throws exception then you have to catch it.

Comment: C#, See my edit.... I have to, I want to, the Point is.. How to avoid the flow control?

Comment: Since advancing to next screen depends on `ExecuteCode` you cannot make it independent. Using flag should be sufficient separation as far as maintainability of code is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit

If you have control over `ExecuteCode()` then instead of throwing an error return a null or false value and use that to check whether to go forward or backward.

#### Original

What if you always go back after the catch statement and put the go forward code at the end of the try, like this:

```
try
{
    ExecuteCode();
    NavigateToNextScreen();
} 
catch(Exception e) 
{
    Log.Write(e);
    ShowErrorMessage();
} 
GoBack();
```

Now go back is the default and it only goes forward if everything executes correctly.

Comment: Still doing Flow Control under the try-catch block... Just like using a goto

Comment: And your code has an error, it will run navigate and GoBack in case there are no errors, so the user is going to stay in the current screen anyways..... You have to place a `return` and that's flow control for sure

Comment: @mFeinstein This is just sudocode. The default is now to go back, so no flow control is happening inside the catch, the catch has absolutely no say as to whether or not you go forward. Inside the try the function would end after NavigateToNextScreen(). It is a subtle difference, but now the control of the flow is controlled entirely by no exceptions being thrown inside ExecuteCode() instead of the catch saying there was an exception and changing the flow.

Comment: Hmm I see, but all the references I read speak about not using the try Catch to do flow control... Not only the catch... But I see your point.... Also, when navigate executes, it will return a and GoBack will execute, but I understand your point in pseudo code.... I will wait for others opinions on this before marking it...

Comment: @mFeinstein Ahh I see, I misunderstood, sorry about that. In that case using the boolean hasError flag is probably the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the obvious?

```
try
{
    if ( ExcuteCode() == false)
    {
        ShowErrorMessage();
        GoBack();
    }
    else
    {
        NavigateToNextScreen();
    }
} 
catch(Exception e) 
{
     Log.Write(e);
     ShowErrorMessage();    
     // handle critical error
}
```

Comment: But there are lots of methods in the framework who doesn't return a bool, they just throw an exception, I will have to wrap them and rethrow the exception, I thought about it, but I felt it was just making too much to be on the right side... Isn't it?

Comment: `ExcuteCode()` isn't a 'framework' method and the question never mentioned the framework.   So the question is poorly written...Isn't it?   BTW:   It's perfectly fine to use exceptions to handle normal database issues like duplicate key or key not found.

Comment: It was just an example of "code that can throw stuff", but I can update the question

Comment: Yes, it is normal, hence my doubt about how to proceed and how people do it without using exceptions as flow control